# Pythonic way to add optional parameters to API request

Tags: python, etherscan

I'am trying to make an API request where I add some optional values but if I don't add them I don't want them to be in the request.

In this case, I would like the parameters to be 'startblock' & 'endblock'

```
def get_transactions_by_address_(self, address, action='txlist'):
    """

    :param address:
    :param action: [txlist, txlistinternal]

    :return:
    """
    token = self.etherscan_api_key
    return requests.get('https://api.etherscan.io/api'
                        '?module=account'
                        f'&action={action}'
                        f'&address={address}'
                        # '&startblock=0'
                        # '&endblock=92702578'
                        '&page=1'
                        '&offset=1000'
                        '&sort=desc'
                        f'&apikey={token}'
                        )
```

I was thinking on adding some conditionals like

```
request_url = 'https://api.etherscan.io/api...'
if startblock:
    request_url = request_url + f'&startblock={startblock}'
if endblock:
    request_url = request_url + f'&endblock={endblock}'
```

But I don't know if it is the most pythonic way to do it and I would like to get other options on how to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `payload` option instead of constructing the URL yourself. For example, create a `dict` containing all the required options, then add additional parameters to the dict as necessary. `requests.get` will build the required URL from the base URL and the values found in your `dict`.

```
options = {
        'module': 'account',
        'action': action,
        'address': address,
        'apikey': token,
        'sort': sort,
        'page': page,
        'offset': offset
    }
if startblock:
    options['startblock'] = startblock
if endblock:
    options['endblock'] = endblock

return requests.get('https://api.etherscan.io/api', params=options)
```

Comment: This will likely also help if one of the parameters contains a special character like &

Comment: Indeed, values will be url-encoded as needed by `request.get`.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to implement is:

```
def get_transactions_by_address_(self, address,
                                 action='txlist',
                                 sort='desc',
                                 page=1,
                                 offset=1000,
                                 startblock=None,
                                 endblock=None):
    
    token = self.etherscan_api_key
    options = {
        'module': 'account',
        'action': action,
        'address': address,
        'apikey': token,
        'sort': sort,
        'page': page,
        'offset': offset
    }
    if startblock:
        options['startblock'] = startblock
    if endblock:
        options['endblock'] = endblock

    return requests.get('https://api.etherscan.io/api',
                        params=options
                        )
```